# Leaflet Mouseout called on MouseOver event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, leaflet

I have a leaflet map where I'm dynamically adding markers.

I want to call the popup for a marker when I hover over it in addition to when I click the marker.

My code is:

```
function makeMarker(){
   var Marker = L.marker...
   Marker.on('mouseover', function(){Marker.bindPopup('HI').openPopup();});

   Marker.on('mouseout', function(){Marker.closePopup();});
}
```

If I comment out the mouseout line, then the popup appears but then I have to click elswhere to close it.
The problem is when I put in the mouseout, at that point, the cursor kinda flickers when it hovers over the marker and nothing shows. I think that the popup is openning but then closing really fast which is why the cursor flickers but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Sounds like you have the behaviour you want by commenting out the 'mouseout' event. What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote down a mix of thought when I said it was working fine. I meant to say that on hover, the popup displays fine but then I have to either close it or click somewhere else in my map as opposed to removing my mouse from the marker. The question is how to keep showing the popup when the mouse is over the marker and how to close it when i remove the mouse from the marker

Answer (score 18):

I know it's an old thread but I've just came across this issue and I thought that I can share my solution. Instead of offsetting the popup, I am preventing the popup from stealing the mouse event using CSS by setting:

```
.my-popup {pointer-events: none;}
```

and assigning my-popup className to the popup:

```
Marker.on('mouseover', function () {Marker.bindPopup('HI', {className: 'my-popup'}).openPopup();})
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Comment: way better solution than shifting the popup.

Comment: That's very elegant

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I found this doesn't apply to the tip (i.e., the triangle that sticks down) of the popup though. Adding `.my-popup .leaflet-popup-tip {pointer-events: none;}` extends this approach to the popup tip.

Answer (score 16):

The popup is actually loading underneath the cursor and 'stealing' the mouse from the Marker, triggering the Marker.mouseout() event, which causes the popup to close and re-triggers the Marker.mouseover() event... and the cycle continues which is why you see the 'flicker'.

I have seen this happen depending on the zoom level (usually when zoomed right out).

Try adding an offset into your popup options to get it out of the way:

```
function makeMarker(){
   var Marker = L.marker...
   Marker.on('mouseover', function(){Marker.bindPopup('HI', {'offset': L.point(0,-50)}).openPopup();});

   Marker.on('mouseout', function(){Marker.closePopup();});
}
```

Comment: This worked nicely. In case anyone is interested, the default offset is (0, 6). http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup

Comment: I can confirm that this also works for me. Found, gratefully, after much trial, error and searching

Answer (score 0):

I also recently came across this problem again too. In case this helps anyone:
As of Leaflet 1.0, you can use L.Tooltip instead of popups with mouseover or other mouse-related events. I've found that it works much more smoothly than making a Popup, and uses less code, especially if you're just opening the popup on hover. In your case it might look like:

```
function makeMarker(){
  var Marker = L.marker...
  Marker.bindTooltip('HI').openPopup();
}
```

And you can use the [`permanent`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tooltip-permanent) boolean flag if you want to keep it open.

In my case I didn't need the popup to open on click (in addition to hover), so that might be a little more complicated. However L.Tooltip has become very widely used and there are other SO questions that deal with this issue.