# Event Handlers dosen't work in popups using react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Im having an issue in react-leaflet when i try to use an eventHandlers in the popups
my logic is that i want when i hover on the marker it opens a popup and when i hover out the popup it turn to closed but it didnt work and this is my code :

```
<Marker
            position={stream.coordinate}
            key={stream.id}
            eventHandlers={{
              mouseover: (e) => {
                e.target.openPopup();
              },
              mouseout: (e) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  e.target.closePopup();
                }, 1000);
              },
              click: (e) => {
                setDisplayRoute(true);
                setSelected(stream.id);
              },
            }}
          >
            <Popup 
              eventHandlers={{
                mouseover: (e) => {
                  e.target.openPopup();
                },
                mouseout: (e) => {
                    e.target.closePopup();
                },
              }}
            >
```

Comment: Can you explain what "didn't work"? Is the popup always open or does the popup never show or something else?

Comment: the eventhandler in popup dosent work at all and i cant find why , i you have any suggestion to cmose the popup when i hoverout the popup not the marker please tell me

Comment: Seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-carlos-9cq1v

Comment: thanks bro but i want it to be displayed until i mouseout from the popup cause the is infos displayed there

Comment: Related, for anyone else fiddling with this kind of issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109336/leaflet-mouseout-called-on-mouseover-event?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It's simple! All you gotta do is add the property "interactive" to your Popup (it also works with the Tooltip).

```
<Popup 
  eventHandlers={{
    mouseover: (e) => {
      e.target.openPopup();
    },
    mouseout: (e) => {
      e.target.closePopup();
    },
  }}
  interactive //Magic happens here
>
```

Hope it helps even though it's been almost 2 years haha